# Kendo grid. Event when selection is become empty

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I need some event when my Kendo grid lose selection (no row selected).

https://dojo.telerik.com/@nick_kingston/IjIYOduw

1. Select one or more rows.
2. Filter by some field that so no selected rows show.
3. Expecting event appearance because now no row selected.

How to implement item 3?

Answer (score 1):

There is no event like `lostSelection`. The `change`-event triggers if the user changes the selection only.

Once the filter was executed, the `dataBound`-event is triggered (as you can see on the demo page https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/events). There you could check for the list of selected items with the method `select` (https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid/methods/select)